# Z-Index conflict when animating fragment transition using the Android Navigation component

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-transitions, android-navigation, android-architecture-navigation

I'm trying to use [Android Navigation](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/navigation/) instead of fragment transaction. There is one problem however which is starting to be cumbersome. Upon using a slide-in animation for the `Enter Animation` the new fragment goes beneath the current fragment. Be sure to check the following video to see the bug in action.
https://youtu.be/gFnXiEyiypM

The bug seems not to be from the `Navigation` component though the hacky solutions ([this](https://carlrice.io/blog/fragmenttransaction-z-index) and [this](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/79443865)) which have been introduced for this specific problem doesn't seem to fix it when `Navigation` is used.
Isn't there a workaround for this until an official fix has been released?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a hacky fix to this problem until an official fix has been released by Google. The solution is to override `onCreateAnimation` with this code:

```
class BaseFragment : Fragment() {

    override fun onCreateAnimation(transit: Int, enter: Boolean, nextAnim: Int): Animation? {
        if (nextAnim == R.anim.fragment_enter) {
            val nextAnimation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(context, nextAnim)
            nextAnimation.setAnimationListener(object : Animation.AnimationListener {
                private var startZ = 0f
                override fun onAnimationStart(animation: Animation) {
                    view?.apply {
                        startZ = ViewCompat.getTranslationZ(this)
                        ViewCompat.setTranslationZ(this, 10f)
                    }
                }

                override fun onAnimationEnd(animation: Animation) {
                    // Short delay required to prevent flicker since other Fragment wasn't removed just yet.
                    view?.apply {
                        this.postDelayed({ ViewCompat.setTranslationZ(this, startZ) }, 100)
                    }
                }

                override fun onAnimationRepeat(animation: Animation) {}
            })
            return nextAnimation
        } else {
            return null
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I will give this a try :)

Comment: This is working for me. Waiting for the Google official fix. The fragment 1.2.0-rc2 release still not fix this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, this issue hasn't been resolved yet by Google. It has been reported here: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/79443865

I struggle to understand how a company like Google is unable to provide something they tell us to do in their Material Guidelines.

Comment: There is this fix actually that I'm going to post as an answer.